# C# WPF backspace event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm new to WPF and C# so what I'm asking is if there is a backspace event like TextChanged event for TextBoxes?
I made a small Library program with renting books and everything is viewed at a ListView.
What I currently did is that you can filter book names just by typing inside the textbox, so if you have 1000 books and you type the letter 'b' then you might have only 150 books starting with 'b'.
The problem is whenever i press backspace, I want it to previously restore it to what it was.
For example: typing "bob" and then deleted b, I get bo and now i want to present what every starts with "bo".
Now I get the idea. All I need is just another textChanged event. but something need to inform that the text was changed, and I need something better then

```
if (backspace key is pressed) { Invoke textChanged }
```

Thx guys!

Well, should i delete the post? maybe some one else will search it someday.
backspace is actually causing a TextChanged event automatically! damn. thx anyway!

Comment: No. There's no need to delete it. If you want, you can answer your own question. Someone searching for "Backspace event" will probably find this and it may help them.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a reference on the msdn site.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/key-press-cs.htm
On a different site (easier to read) This though looks like it is for Win Forms.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed");
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed");
        }
    }
```

Looks like you need to create an event that fires on a key down, then get the value of that key. I think there is a `Keys.Backspace` but to know for sure let intellisense help you.

Comment: First of all thx for your response but I actually know now that my question was extremely stupid. I will edit my post.